# Thunderbird doesn't see the profile after an update

Tags: windows, thunderbird

After updating Thunderbird to the latest version (78.7.1 32-bit), I was welcomed by the "Set Up Your Existing Email Address" dialog. I can see that my profile folder is still there and the bulk of the data in it is present (it's several GB in size). However, Thunderbird refuses to see any of it.

I have tried to create a new profile using the existing folder, with the same outcome. Is there a way to recover my profile? I have a backup of the profile which is up-to-date w.r.t. accounts settings, but of course not w.r.t. latest e-mails I have sent/received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For now, I have solved this by renaming the latest of `prefs-NN.js` files to `prefs.js`. More detailed answers about which files keep actual profile settings and must be restored from backup are welcome.